# Extract all users along with yoast metadata description

Tags: mysql, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, users

We currently have a authors list page which shows all users which have at least 1 published post.

Within this page I'd like to also show the description of the user, but take this from the metadata description field which Yoast SEO plugin adds to we don't have to duplicate data.

From what I've been told "The author meta description added with Yoast SEO can be found in the wp_usermeta table, with the meta_key wpseo_metadesc. Hopefully, this helps your developer extract it and use it on your website."

So is there a way in wordpress to perform the following query:

1. selects the users id, firstname, lastname, email address and the wpseo_metadesc
2. where the user has at least one published post.

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, this can be achieved by using the function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/